# Почему функция open() не дает мне подгрузить файл 2 раза

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

При второй команде /start код крашится , и выдает ошибку :

```
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.
Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty
```

Сам код:

```
import telebot                                                                                                                     
from telebot import types                                                                                                          
import os        
                                                                                                              
site = 'qiwi.com/n/NEFFYXXX1337'                                                                                                   
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')                                                            
file = open('sak.jpg', 'rb')                                                                                                       


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])                                                                                           
def start(message):                                                                                                                
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()                                                                                        
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Аренда номеров", callback_data="number")                                            
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Proxy/VPN", callback_data="vpn")                                                    
    keyboard.add(button1,button2)                                                                                                  
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file, 'Добро пожаловать в Sakura Service!\nВыберите нужный вам раздел',reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Потому что после того, как вы прочитали файл первый раз, вы не передвигаете курсор обратно в начало файла, и он остаётся в конце файла, из-за чего при втором чтении не читается ничего, потому что курсор уже и так дошёл до конца файла

Comment: а можете помочь убрать эту проблему??

Answer (score 0):

После полного чтения файла указатель файла остаётся в конце файла и последующие чтения файла дают пустой файл, на что и ругается Телеграм.

Вариант 1: открывать файл каждый раз заново (это не так уж и долго):

```py
with open('sak.jpg', 'rb') as file:                                                      
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file, 'Добро пожаловать в Sakura Service!\nВыберите нужный вам раздел',reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Вариант 2: перемотка указателя в начало:

```py
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file, 'Добро пожаловать в Sakura Service!\nВыберите нужный вам раздел',reply_markup=keyboard)
file.seek(0)
```